# Start fragment from RecyclerViewAdapter without interface

Tags: android

I am looking for the newest and most simple but correct approach to start fragment and passing data from listFragment.

Adapter:

```
class MyRideListItemRecyclerViewAdapter(private val values: List<RideWithSegments>) : 
RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRideListItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.fragment_rides, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(view)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = values[position]
    holder.itemDate.text = "" + item.ride.time
    holder.itemName.text = item.ride.name
  
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        Log.d("DTAG", "Clicked: " + item.ride.id)
        //maybe load fragment here

    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int = values.size

inner class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    val itemDate: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.item_date)
    val itemName: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.item_name)//??
  
}
```

}

In fragment:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, 
savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rides_list, container, false)

    // Set the adapter
    if (view is RecyclerView) {
        val with = with(view) {
            layoutManager = when {
                columnCount <= 1 -> LinearLayoutManager(context)
                else -> GridLayoutManager(context, columnCount)
            }

            lifecycleScope.launch {
                val rides = DataBaseHelper.getAllRidesFromDB()
                adapter = MyRideListItemRecyclerViewAdapter(rides)
            }


        }

            //view.addOnItemTouchListener() maybe like so?
    }
    return view
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do it by passing the onClick as a lambda to the adapter like so:

In the activity/fragment

```
viewAdapter = MainAdapter {
          //navigation code here
        }
```

the adapter and the ViewHolder:

```
class MainAdapter(private val cl: (wallpaper: WallHavenResponse) -> Unit) :
    PagingDataAdapter<WallHavenResponse, MyViewHolder>(diffCallback) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val imageView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item, parent, false) as ImageView
        return MyViewHolder(imageView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val post = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(getItem(position)!!, cl)
    }

}


class MyViewHolder(itemView: ImageView) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    fun bind(data: WallHavenResponse, clickListener: (WallHavenResponse) -> Unit) {
        itemView.setOnClickListener { clickListener(data) }
    }
}
```

you can see the full implementation in this [project](https://github.com/zedlabs/WallPortal/)